# Tabbing jeditable fields and non-jeditable fields

Tags: jquery, jeditable

On my website I have several forms that are using the judicable plugin for edit in place, but then also have select tags mixed in there and a few upload inputs. I was trying to set it up so that when you hit the tab key it selects the next field. So I tried to set it up with query to do this.

```
$('.edit').bind('keydown', function(evt) {
  if(evt.keyCode==9) {
    var nextBox='';
    var currentBoxIndex=$(".edit").index(this);

     if (currentBoxIndex == ($(".edit").length-1)) {
          alert('next please');        
       } else {
            nextBox=$(".edit").eq(currentBoxIndex+1); 
            $(this).find("input").blur();
            $(nextBox).click();  
            return false;    
       }
  };
});
```

And this works with the jeditable fields, but it skips any kind of select field or upload in between. Is there any way to include the select fields and such so that it truly is tabbing to the next input?

Comment: It would be useful if you can provide us with a working example page (or rather, an example page where everything worse except your problem). Right now, setting up an example page would cost anyone wanting to answer this question far more time than actually answering it (which is probably why no one answered it yet).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I would have set up an example page if that was possible, but unfortunately it is not. Jeditable is a plug in that does not work well in jsFiddle, trust me I've tried. And even if that would have worked, the company that I am working for does not wish me to share their html code for some odd reason.

Comment: You don't need to share everything, just a (simple) test/example page to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Again, I cannot replicate the jEditable in a jsFiddle and that is really the whole point of this question.

Comment: I never said anything about jsFiddle. jsFiddle isn't the only way to setup a test page, you can just put some html/js/css in a page somewhere...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I was just using jsFiddle as an example. I have tried many different pages such as codepen and such. It is just not possible. And putting something on my own server is frowned upon here because the page will most likely change.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the HTML `tabindex` attribute? It works fine for jeditable fields.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6RfM8/)

Comment: That doesn't work... The goal is to tab to the next field...that just saves the value. And the point is to tab back and forth between jeditable fields and regular selects.

Comment: Updated here with a regular select: http://jsfiddle.net/6RfM8/1/, You can add regular selects into the mix with their own tabindex and it works fine. `tabindex` exists to control the order in which elements are focused when the user tabs. Additionally, you could use `event: focus` option with jeditable and not have to simulate the `click` event.

Comment: That is still not working for me, not even in the fiddle. It just saves the value and that is not what I wish to do here.

Comment: The point of my fiddle was not about "saving", I've never even seen jeditable prior to attempting to help you. It was merely that you don't need to use javascript to specify how the tab key works. I literally took the samples directly from their website. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but I don't see the tabbing working at all in your example.